# How to create a new MySQL database with go-sql-driver

Tags: mysql, go

I'm working on Golang script that automatically clone a database.
I'm using go-sql-driver but i can't find in the documentation a way to create a new database.
Connection to MySQL require an URL scheme like:

```
user:password@tcp(localhost:3306)/database_name
```

But the database not exists yet, I just want to connect to the server and then create a new one.

How can I do that? I have to use another driver?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can perfectly use the go-sql-driver. However, you need to use a mysql user which has the proper access rights to create new databases.

Here is an example:

```
func create(name string) {

   db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "admin:admin@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/")
   if err != nil {
       panic(err)
   }
   defer db.Close()

   _,err = db.Exec("CREATE DATABASE "+name)
   if err != nil {
       panic(err)
   }

   _,err = db.Exec("USE "+name)
   if err != nil {
       panic(err)
   }

   _,err = db.Exec("CREATE TABLE example ( id integer, data varchar(32) )")
   if err != nil {
       panic(err)
   }
}
```

Note that the database name is not provided in the connection string. We just create the database after the connection (CREATE DATABASE command), and switch the connection to use it (USE command).

Note: the VividCortex guys maintain a nice database/sql tutorial and documentation at http://go-database-sql.org/index.html

Comment: `database/sql` maintains a connection pool. I've seen "Error 1046: No database selected" pop up when the a new connection is made. Is there a way to run `db.Exec("USE "+name)` automatically after `database/sql` opens a new connection?

Comment: Yes sure ... just put the database name in the connection string: "user:password@tcp(hostname:port)/dbname"

Comment: Ah, so first `sql.Open(...)` without database name and run `db.Exec("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " + name)`. Then close the connection, `sql.Open(.../name)` *with* the database name to create a database and use it safely with the pool.

Comment: Honest quention: Isn't this a textbook example on how to open yourself up for sql injection? Is there no way to make this work using the placeholder parameters?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to create a new database if it does not exist, and use it directly in your program, be aware that `database/sql` maintains a connection pool.

Therefore the opened database connection, should preferably contain the database name. I've seen `"Error 1046: No database selected"` when `database/sql` opens a new connection after using `db.Exec("USE "+name)` manually.

```
func createAndOpen(name string) *sql.DB {

   db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "admin:admin@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/")
   if err != nil {
       panic(err)
   }
   defer db.Close()

   _,err = db.Exec("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS "+name)
   if err != nil {
       panic(err)
   }
   db.Close()

   db, err = sql.Open("mysql", "admin:admin@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/" + name)
   if err != nil {
       panic(err)
   }
   defer db.Close()
   return db
}
```

Comment: The `return db` will be closed since you called `defer db.Close()`.